# Script to capture everything on screen

Tags: python, linux, scripting, automation, recording

So I have this python3 script that does a lot of automated testing for me, it takes roughly 20 minutes to run, and some user interaction is required.  It also uses paramiko to ssh to a remote host for a separate test.

Eventually, I would like to hand this script over to the rest of my team however, it has one feature missing: evidence collection!

I need to capture everything that appears on the terminal to a file.  I have been experimenting with the Linux command 'script'.  However, I cannot find an automated method of starting script, and executing the script.

I have a command in /usr/bin/

```
script log_name;python3.5 /home/centos/scripts/test.py
```

When I run my command, it just stalls.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually managed to do it in python3, took a lot of work, but here is the python solution:

```
def record_log(output):
try:
    with open(LOG_RUN_OUTPUT, 'a') as file:
        file.write(output)
except:
    with open(LOG_RUN_OUTPUT, 'w') as file:
        file.write(output)


def execute(cmd, store=True):
proc = Popen(cmd.encode("utf8"), shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output = "\n".join((out.decode()for out in proc.communicate()))
template = '''Command:\n====================\n%s\nResult:\n====================\n%s'''
output = template % (cmd, output)
print(output)
if store:
    record_log(output)
return output


# SSH function
def ssh_connect(start_message, host_id, user_name, key, stage_commands):
print(start_message)
try:
    ssh.connect(hostname=host_id, username=user_name, key_filename=key, timeout=120)
except:
    print("Failed to connect to " + host_id)
for command in stage_commands:
    try:
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    except:
        input("Paused, because " + command + " failed to run.\n  Please verify and press enter to continue.")
    else:
        template = '''Command:\n====================\n%s\nResult:\n====================\n%s'''
        output = ssh_stderr.read() + ssh_stdout.read()
        output = template % (command, output)
        record_log(output)
        print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is a redirection of the output to a file what you need ?

```
python3.5 /home/centos/scripts/test.py > output.log 2>&1
```

Or if you want to keep the output on the terminal AND save it into a file:

```
python3.5 /home/centos/scripts/test.py 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this, and ended up with a solution that combined [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/) and [ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en).

ttyrec produces output files that can be played back with a few different player applications - I use [TermTV](http://www.fact-project.org/termtv/) and [IPBT](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/ipbt/).

If memory serves, I had to use pexpect to launch ttyrec (as well as my test's other commands) because I was using Jenkins to schedule the execution of my test, and pexpect seemed to be the easiest way to get a working interactive shell in a Jenkins job.

In your situation you might be able to get away with using just ttyrec, and skip the pexpect step - try running `ttyrec -e command` as mentioned in the ttyrec docs.

Finally, on the topic of interactive shells, there's an alternative to pexpect named "empty" that I've had some success with too - see http://empty.sourceforge.net/. If you're running Ubuntu or Debian you can install empty with `apt-get install empty-expect`